# Calling repository methods from another repository C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a "DatabaseController" Class, which contains several repository classes, each for every table in a database, and they only perform crud operations. My issue is this.

When i delete an entry , i call the corresponding repository method. I also need to call some delete methods from other tables (repositories). What is the best approach to do this?

Example Code:

DatabaseController Class

```
public DatabaseController(){
        this.dbContext = new WSATDbContext();
    }

    private IWSATGenericRepository<Restmethod> _restmethod ;
    private IWSATGenericRepository<Soapservice> _soapservice ;

    public IWSATGenericRepository<Restmethod> Restmethod
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_restmethod == null)
            {
                _restmethod = new RestmethodRepository(dbContext);

            }
            return _restmethod;            
        }
    } 

    public IWSATGenericRepository<Soapservice> Soapservice
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_soapservice == null)
            {
                _soapservice = new SoapserviceRepository(dbContext);

            }
            return _soapservice;            
        }
    }
```

Example Repository:

```
public class RestmethodRepository : IWSATGenericRepository<Restmethod>
{

    public RestmethodRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Null DbContext");
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.dbSet = dbContext.Set<Restmethod>();
    }

    private DbContext dbContext { get; set; }
    private DbSet<Restmethod> dbSet { get; set; }

    public Restmethod get(int id)
    {   
        Restmethod restmethod = dbSet.Find(id) ;    
        dbContext.Entry(restmethod).Collection(s => s.methodkeywords).Load() ;

        return restmethod ;
    }


    public Restmethod delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = this.get(id);

        //I want to call some other repo methods here

        dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        try
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: Is it good practice to pass the "DatabaseController" UOW class as an argument to each repository? Are there any theoretical problems with that? This is an academic project , so i'd like to stay as formal as possible.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Closers: this is not "too broad".

Comment: Your "DatabaseController" is usually called a UnitOfWork. The pattern is often criticized because a DbContext is already a UoW and the `DbSet<>`s are already repositories.

Comment: Also, the lack of `IDisposable` here is kind of scary.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i have implemented the IDisposable interface, this is just a sample code to show you how my code "looks like".

Comment: @Tyddlywink I have read this article , but it doesn't answer my question (or did i miss something obvious?).